# Mule ESB 3.8 json output dw Script

Tags: json, mule, esb

I have the input json like this:

```
 {
      "person": {
        "personinfo": [
          {
            "VAR_KEY": "name",
            "VAR_VAL": "jack"
          },
          {
            "VAR_KEY": "sex",
            "VAR_VAL": "male"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

and I want to get the output like this

```
{
          "person": {
            "personinfo": [
              {
                "name":"jack"
              },
              {
                "sex":"male"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

how to write the mule esb dw script? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
person : {
    personinfo : payload.person.personinfo map {
       ($.VAR_KEY) : $.VAR_VAL
}}
```

Comment: If i want to get the output like this ,how to change the script?thank you{
          "person": {
            "personinfo": {
                "name":"jack",
                "sex":"male"
          }
        }}

Comment: @Zeng xijin , this should work . personinfo :  {(payload.person.personinfo map {
 ($.VAR_KEY) : $.VAR_VAL
})}

Comment: @Zeng xijin, my email contact is anupamvbhusari@gmail.com.